# Turn off fade/transition animation on startup in JetBrains v2023 IDEs

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, clion, jetbrains-ide, datagrip

Starting with IntelliJ, CLion, WebStorm etc. 2023 version there is some fade/transition animation during startup.

How to disable it?

I'm also using `-Dnosplash=true` in `vmoptions` to disable splash screen.

Comment: It's a feature of the New UI. Disable the New UI in Settings | Appearance & Behavior | New UI | Enable new UI.

Comment: Sadly, but nope, i didn't ever used Beta UI within this installations, the tick is disabled. Env: Arch, KDE.

Comment: Maybe we are talking about different behavior then. IDE is making a screenshot of the frame when you close the project and then shows this screenshot while the project frame is initialized. It also fades the UI until it's fully initialized. While it's possible to disable the screenshot (selfie) feature, it's not possible to disable fading. If you don't like this behavior, please file an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA.

Comment: For now, New UI is enabled by default. Do you still experience the issue?